# SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: database "test-database" does not exist when i try to migrate in laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql

so im trying to use php artisan migrate but i get this error :

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  database "test-database" does not exist (SQL: select * from           information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

the problem is there is no database "test-database"
here is my env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=Batman
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

and here is my database.conf

```
'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'Batman'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'postgres'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '123456'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],
```

i really dont get it. please help

Comment: Have you used the database name `test-database` at any point in the past? If so, try `php artisan config:clear` to clear your configuration cache.

Comment: ok yeah that worked thank you, but now it says there is no Batman database. but i created it on localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: Well, that's not going to work, because phpMyAdmin manages MySQL databases, and your database configuration is for PostgreSQL.

Comment: oh. do you know any good managers that would work on ubuntu? im sorry im not really good at this yet, just a beginner

Comment: I'm on a Mac, so can't offer one from personal experience, but https://www.pgadmin.org/ is popular.

Answer (score -2):

try pgAdmin, it has a deb package, it should work fine on Ubuntu.